# How do I slice *ngFor in a component based on the components it is injected into?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

The following code is a component that i need to inject in other components:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 [...]" *ngFor="let course of courses">
        <div class="card">
            [...]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that in one of the components it is injected in, I need to apply a `| slice:0:4` in the ngFor to display less data. For this reason, I modified the child component and made it so the data from the parent components is sent to the child component. So I removed the `.row` and `.col-12` divs and put it into the parent components, this way I can use the slice only in the parent component I need to.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 [...]" *ngFor="let course of courses | slice:0:4">
        <app-child-component [course]="course"></app-child-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Child component now is like this:

```
<div class="card">
    [...]
</div>
```

The problem now is that I need to apply CSS classes to the child component's `.row` that must be visible everywhere but this way I have to modify every single parent component's `.row`, so more useless code. I also assume this way I'm not using Angular's components concept the way it is meant to.

Is there a way to use `| slice` and kind of "send it" from a single parent component to the child component like i'm doing now with `[corso]="corso"` in `<app-component [corso]="corso"></app-component>`?

Hoping I explained this well. Thank you.

Comment: You can pass slice number from the parent component to child component as `@Input`

Comment: @Sameer so setting `:start` and `:end` in `| slice` as variables?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely what you need to do, but if I were to do some complex slicing, I would do it in the .ts side of things in a new array, then use that to do an *ngFor. Maybe you can create a class with all the slicing information you need and pass that into a component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Child component ts
@Input() sliceStart = 0; //default to `0` if not passed
@Input() sliceEnd = 4; //default to `4` if not passed

courses = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'Javascript', 'Angular'];
```

```html
<!-- Child component html -->
<div *ngFor="let course of courses | slice: sliceStart:sliceEnd">
  {{course}}
</div>
```

```
<!-- Parent component html -->
<app-child-component [sliceEnd]="2"></app-child-component>
```

[Stacblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-for-slice-hzxxmr)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!